# Xcode logs showing constraint errors, however there're no errors in Storyboard file

Tags: ios, xcode, nslayoutconstraint

This is surprise, I'm not sure, but my Xcode's debug logs showing me, some random constraint errors however, there're no errors in Storyboard file (and it doesn't effect anywhere in my app).

I'm posting this question just to make sure that there's some serious issue or something that I'm missing from my side?

Here's my log:

```
2016-02-04 17:46:17.432 MyApp[3586:198217] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe19aeebd00 V:[UIButton:0x7fe19aeedee0(44)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe19aef0cf0 V:[UIButton:0x7fe19aeedee0]-(-1)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe19aeed8e0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe19aef0d40 V:|-(0)-[UIButton:0x7fe19aeedee0]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe19aeed8e0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe19d007580 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe19aeed8e0(44)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe19aeebd00 V:[UIButton:0x7fe19aeedee0(44)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-02-04 17:46:17.434 MyApp[3586:198217] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe19d0124a0 V:[UIButton:0x7fe19d0121f0(44)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe19d014420 V:[UIButton:0x7fe19d0121f0]-(-1)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe19d012060 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe19d014470 V:|-(0)-[UIButton:0x7fe19d0121f0]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe19d012060 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe19d00bb90 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe19d012060(44)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe19d0124a0 V:[UIButton:0x7fe19d0121f0(44)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-02-04 17:46:17.435 MyApp[3586:198217] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe19d019820 V:[UIButton:0x7fe19d019570(44)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe19d01b7a0 V:[UIButton:0x7fe19d019570]-(-1)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe19d0193e0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe19d01b7f0 V:|-(0)-[UIButton:0x7fe19d019570]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe19d0193e0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe19d01f130 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe19d0193e0(44)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe19d019820 V:[UIButton:0x7fe19d019570(44)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-02-04 17:46:17.436 MyApp[3586:198217] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe19d020640 V:[UIButton:0x7fe19d020390(44)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe19d022460 V:[UIButton:0x7fe19d020390]-(-1)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe19d020200 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe19d0224b0 V:|-(0)-[UIButton:0x7fe19d020390]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe19d020200 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe19ac90e20 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe19d020200(44)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe19d020640 V:[UIButton:0x7fe19d020390(44)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-02-04 17:46:17.438 MyApp[3586:198217] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe19d027410 V:[UIButton:0x7fe19d027160(44)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe19d029390 V:[UIButton:0x7fe19d027160]-(-1)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe19d026fd0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe19d0293e0 V:|-(0)-[UIButton:0x7fe19d027160]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe19d026fd0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe19ac7da90 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe19d026fd0(44)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe19d027410 V:[UIButton:0x7fe19d027160(44)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-02-04 17:46:17.439 MyApp[3586:198217] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe19d02e2c0 V:[UIButton:0x7fe19d02e010(44)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe19d030240 V:[UIButton:0x7fe19d02e010]-(-1)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe19d02de80 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe19d030290 V:|-(0)-[UIButton:0x7fe19d02e010]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe19d02de80 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe19af28d90 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe19d02de80(44)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe19d02e2c0 V:[UIButton:0x7fe19d02e010(44)]>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Here's my Storyboard views list:

[image]

Configuration:

Xcode v.7.1.1

iOS v.9.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constraints given by you are breaking somewhere. That's why it is showing an error. So identify the constraints that you don't need and remove them. (e.g. Repeated constraints or the constraints that doesn't make any sense such as you are giving leading and trailing and also fixed width.)

Comment: Is there any way to identify those constraints easily?

Comment: add a snapshot of your constrains. I guess they are breaking on your tableView

Comment: I don't know any particular method to identify them but you get to know by practice

Comment: Alright, thanks! I will look for this in initial screens of the app. Is it a serious matter or its fine as I'll be going to submit my app on store?

Comment: It's not serious but if run your app in other devices with different screen size it may misplace the original position

Comment: To know where the constraints are breaking, keep observing the console. As soon as the screen containing broken constraints appears, the console will show the error.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be using a custom table view cell. Did you check the cell's .xib file for constraints?

Edit:
Looks like there is an issue with the cell's button height. Check if you are setting both height as well as top and bottom constraints for the button. If yes, that's what causing the problem.

To solve it, remove either the button's height constraint or the top or bottom constraint.

Comment: Yes, I have set constraints for those xib's as well. Btw, I'm using storyboard environment, for some of the views I'm preferring xibs.

Comment: Looks like there is an issue with the cell height. Removing the cell's button height constraint should solve it.

Answer (score 1):

The "UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height" constraint is one set by the layout engine by default. The error you are getting means that the height you set for your cell conflicts with the one the system thinks it should be.

A valid option would be lowering the priority of your constraint. This will resolve the conflict. If it also produces the desired layout, you're good. Is your intent to have varying height cells?

Answer (score 0):

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe19d027410 V:[UIButton:0x7fe19d027160(44)]>",

"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe19d029390 V:[UIButton:0x7fe19d027160]-(-1)-|   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe19d026fd0 )>",

"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe19d0293e0 V:|-(0)-[UIButton:0x7fe19d027160]   (Names: '|':UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe19d026fd0 )>",

"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe19ac7da90 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7fe19d026fd0(44)]>"


button.height = 44.

button.bottom = contentView.bottom+1

button.top = contentView.top;

contentView.height = 44
```

.

when all come up together button should have 45 height. but you explicitly set it to 44.
remove height constraint for button or, make `button.bottom = contentView.bottom`.